# Make disabled Image in PictureBox more noticable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `PictureBox` with an `Image`:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pbMyWarning;
    ...
    this.picApprovalSaveChangesWarning.Image = MyImages.Resources.Warning;
    pbMyWarning.Enabled = true;
```

It gets disabled upon certain use actions:

```
pbMyWarning.Enabled = false;
```

However, there is little or no difference in the appearance when enabling/disabling it.
How can I make it noticable?

Comment: You could use 2 images - one bright, one greyed.  Enabling/disabling the control does nothing to the image assigned to it.  You should load the image(s) into an array and assign from there.  You are creating a new image each time

Comment: Consider ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled() to generate the 2nd image.

Comment: @Plutonix: Thanks I've done just that now, created a grey image. This works fine.If you want to make that an answer, I'll check it off.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the suggestion.